# Flutter webview showing error on Flutter web

Tags: flutter, webview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfi9q.png)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'webview',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: WebViewWidget(controller: WebViewController()
          ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
          ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
          ..setNavigationDelegate(
            NavigationDelegate(
              onProgress: (int progress) {
                // Update loading bar.
              },
              onPageStarted: (String url) {},
              onPageFinished: (String url) {},
              onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
              onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
                if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
                  return NavigationDecision.prevent;
                }
                return NavigationDecision.navigate;
              },
            ),
          )
          ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'))),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to include the error message as _text_ rather than as an image.

Answer (score 0):

The package that your'e using ([`webview_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) **isn't supported** for Flutter Web.

As you can see by the documentation, it only support Android and iOS:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way i can configure it to support flutter web

Comment: @NannoyProgramming Use a different package. such as https://pub.dev/packages/easy_web_view

Comment: im not able to login on the embedded site